# Save in a file first 7 file in the directory /bin that starts with c

Tags: find, pipe, wc, write

I have write a command in the shell of linux to count the file (in total 8) starting with 'c'in the directory /bin

```
find /bin/[c]* -type f | wc -l
```

What I wish to do now, it's save the name of the first 7 files in a text file, but I can not find the right command to join to my pipe.

Comment: Note that `find` is usually called like this `find [starting-point] ... -name {names_to_searchs_for} ...`. What your command does, it expands the `/bin/[c]*` to a list of all files and directories starting with `c` in your `/bin` and then uses these files as starting-points for `find`. This way, it will also list all regular files in possible directories like `/bin/commands1/`. Instead you should use `find /bin -name 'c*' -type f` (Note the single quotes around the search term `c*`). Also, you don't need the brackets `[...]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find /bin/[c]* -type f | head -n 7 > textfile
```

Comment: @Alexander Thanks. The only task to put accepted is that I need to save this infos in a text file

Comment: @GianniSpear. Just add `> filename` at the end of line.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the first 7 in alphabetical order, with `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' /bin/c*(.[1,7]) > list.txt
```

If you mean

- the 7 oldest ones, add the `Om` glob qualifier (`c*(.Om[1,7])`)
- the 7 newest ones, add the `om` glob qualifier instead
- the 7 smallest: `oL`
- 7 biggest: `OL`

Note that in `find /bin/[c]*`, it's the shell that expands that glob and passes the resulting files (alphabetically sorted) as separate arguments to `find`.

Beware that if any of those files are directories, `find` will start to descend into them and list their content (in an unspecified order)

You'd want:

```
find /bin/c* -prune -type f | head -n 7 > file.txt
```

Where `-prune` is to prevent `find` from descending into any directory. But beware that using `head` that way only works if the file names don't contain newline characters (most likely the case in `/bin` but not guaranteed in the general case).